# Change background/highlight-color of selected ListBox item based on data

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to change the background/hightlight color of a *selected* ListBox item using data binding. This is what I have and tried, but it's not working. I'm not sure how to get the resources section to have the "current item" context.

Color is a property on every item displayed (and has a different value for each item).

```
<ListBox x:Name="Categorie" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="{Binding /Color}" />
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="{Binding /Color}" />
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another work around can be to set the background using your color property and setting the HightlightBrushKey to Transparent.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Trigger` to achieve that:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Note that for this binding to work, you *must* have a property called `Color` on the data item objects that are set as the `ListBox.ItemsSource`.

UPDATE >>>

Ok, so that was my bad... I forgot that `SolidColorBrush` is not a `FrameworkElement` and is `Freezable`, so they cannot be used in a `Binding`... you have a few options:

Either create your colour(s) as `StaticResource` object(s):

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Color}" />
</Trigger>
```

Or you could bind the `Background` property to the `Color` object using a `Converter` of some kind:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" Background="{Binding Color, Converter={StaticResource 
SomeColourConverter}}" />
```

Comment: I've put that snippet in the `<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>` but I still get the default color. I think the highlight-style overrides the background. If I use a color directly in my example it works, with databinding it doesn't.

Comment: Look in the Output window - do you have any errors?... if so, what do they say? Do you have a property on your data item to bind to named `Color`?

Comment: There's an error: `System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Color; DataItem=null; target element is 'SolidColorBrush' (HashCode=21176298); target property is 'Color' (type 'Color')`. I do have a Color property on the items. I seems like the context is not available in the style section.

Comment: @Robert Massa: Your `Binding` does not work (in your example), because the `SolidColorBrush` is placed on a resource. In the Resource `Binding` does not work, because it is not part of the visual tree or template.

Comment: Well, if I make it a static resource, it's exactly that right? I'd like the color to be dependent on the selected item, not static. Or am I missing something?